# Lock OfficeRibonLabel size

Tags: vsto, office-addins

I have an Excel VSTO plug-in which displays error messages in a RibbonLabel.

Changing the label text causes it to resize which causes its containing RibbonGroup to resize which moves the last group separator right and left with each message. This looks very annoying.

[image]

Is there a way to freeze Ribbon control size or, alternatively, any other way to display immediately visible error message which will not block the document itself (i.e. NOT message box)?

Comment: You could write the label to a task pane instead of the ribbon or use the status bar. `excelApp.StatusBar = String.Format("Processing line {0} on {1}.",rows,rowNum);`

Comment: I have a few examples of how to use the task pane in my GitHub project if that helps.  https://github.com/Excel-projects

Comment: Yes, I know task pane can be used and, AFAIK, it gives more control over its child controls but, unfortunately, since all my functionality is in Ribbon I prefer not to waste significant part of screen width just to occasionally display a message.

Comment: @aduguid Status bar is a good idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write the label to the status bar.

`excelApp.StatusBar = String.Format("Processing line {0} on {1}.",rows,rowNum);`